# App developers: Invalidate privisiong profiles when add/remove App Capabilities

Tags: app-store, ios-universal-links

My application it's already published on the App store.
I need to add "Associate Domains" to capabilities so I can use Universal Links in my app.
If I save the edit of the capabilities list, a popup appears:

> Modify App Capabilities
> Adding or removing any capabilities will invalidate any provisioning profiles that include this App ID and they must be regenerated for future use.

This will compromise the future updates of the app and the version that is still on the store?

Comment: did you get the answer?

Comment: I've created a new provisioning profile to use in the next update.